# Eclipse plugin dropins installation

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I have a locally developed eclipse plugin jar file. I was using Eclipse Helios in which I just copied the jar file inside eclipse\dropins folder, with this the plugin is deployed and I could use the same in my projects

Now I have upgraded to Eclipse Luna and I have copied the same jar file inside eclipse\dropins folder, I could not see my plugin installed. I tried all the suggestions shown in web but still not able to deploy.

Could any one please let me know the detailed process of deploying my own jar file as a plugin in Eclipse Luna

Regards,
Manohar

Comment: *All* the suggestions? What are they?

Comment: I have tried the options given in the url http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fp2_dropins_format.html. Still i am not able to deploy my plugin